# GROUP BY including 0 where none present

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of `lists`, each of which contains `posts`. I want a query that tells me how many `posts` each `list` has, including an entry with a 0 for each list that doesn't have any posts.

eg.

`posts`:

```
id  |  list_id
--------------
1   |   1  
2   |   1
3   |   2
4   |   2
```

`lists`:

```
id
---
1
2
3
```

should return:

```
list_id | num_posts
-------------------
1       | 2
2       | 2
3       | 0
```

I have done so using the following query, but it feels a bit stupid to effectively do the grouping and then execute another sub-query to fill in the blanks:

```
WITH "count_data" AS (
  SELECT "posts"."list_id" AS "list_id", COUNT(DISTINCT "posts"."id") AS "num_posts"
  FROM "posts"
  INNER JOIN "lists" ON "posts"."list_id" = "lists"."id"
  GROUP BY "posts"."list_id"
)
SELECT "lists"."id", COALESCE("count_data"."num_posts", 0)
FROM "lists"
LEFT JOIN "count_data" ON "count_data"."list_id" = "lists"."id"
ORDER BY "count_data"."num_posts" DESC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'll be more efficient to left join directly, avoiding a seq scan with a big merge join in the process:

```
select lists.id as list_id, count(posts.list_id) as num_posts
from lists
left join posts on posts.list_id = lists.id
group by lists.id
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of `GROUPING BY` `lists.id`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this should work:

```
SELECT List_ID, ISNULL(b.list_ID,0)
FROM lists a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT list_ID, COUNT(*)
      FROM posts
      GROUP BY list_ID
     )b
ON a.ID = b.list_ID
```